# Aspnet core application is not running after docker host or container restart

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm running containers with restart policy as always through docker-compose, it has two images RabbitMq & AspNetCore,it all works fine for the first time.

when I restart the host or docker containers then RabbitMq is running fine and accessible through **localhost:8080**  even after restarting, but aspnet core project container is running but I can't access through internal and external ( **localhost:5001/api/home/get**) ports.

Docker compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  aspnetcoreenvironmentvariables.api:
    image: aspnetcoreenvironmentvariables
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AspNetCoreEnvironmentVariables.API/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    restart: always
```

Docker compose override

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  aspnetcoreenvironmentvariables.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="connection"
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
  rabbitmq: 
    ports:
      - "8080:15672"
```

Below is error from docker
 [image]

Comment: try using some different port than 80, may be 80 port is being used by some other application and can't be allocated.

Comment: Okay thanks, i think the port should be free because we have restarted the container

Comment: the port may have been used by some another application. run `netstat -ntlp` to see the list of used port. If port 80 is not in the list then try running docker as root

Comment: No, command it self is wrong